# Modo Noche en Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy intentando activar el tema `dark` de ionic en la aplicación, pero realmente no he conseguido ningún resultado.

La idea es que con un `ion-toggle` pueda cambiar entre el modo `light` y `dark`.

Dispongo de un método `nightmode` donde se le pasa por parámetro `true` o `false` (el valor del ion-toggle).

```js
public nightmode(bool:boolean){
    this.ls.updateVariable('nightMode', bool);

    const systemDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
    systemDark.addListener(this.colorTest);
    if(bool){
      document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    }else{
      document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    }
  }
```

En `variables.css` ya viene un estilo para modo oscuro. ¿Como cambio a estas variables usando `typescript`? He estado probando diferentes tutoriales y no me han funcionado.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con:

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.4
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente no sé si esta solución es factible pero me ha funcionado. El problema recidía en que en `variables.css` las etiquetas `body` no tiene `body.dark` como en el ejemplo que viene en la [documentación](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode).

En ese caso tan solo sustituí el bloque `dark` de mi `variable.css` por la de la documentación y:

Para activarlo:

```js
document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
```

Para desactivarlo:

```js
document.body.classList.remove('dark');
```